# why this javascript function in JS code is started with a pre-bracket like this and ended with a pair of brackets?? (function() { })();

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is it because we want to run this function in loop? or anything else? (This is the code for display of multiple texts with fade in and out effects.)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">3rd quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">4th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">5th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">6th quote</h2>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.quotes {display: none;}
```

JS Code:

```
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

Comment: see: [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Answer (score 3):

It means that the function will invoke immediately without you calling the it.

See -> https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/js-self-invoking-functions.html

**Edit**: 
as Felix Kling mentioned
**to be clear**: you do call it but you calling as soon as the function defined unlike normal functions that can be called on events or as callbacks

Comment: *"without you calling the it"* It is called. That's what the `()` at the end mean. It's the same as `foo()` except that `foo` is replaced with a function definition.